# Vue router and Bootstrap

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-strap

I'm using Vue with `vue-router` and `vue-strap`. I'm trying to register components from `vue-strap`, but the examples look like this:

```
var alert = require('vue-strap').alert;

new Vue({
  components: {
    alert: alert
  }
})
```

`vue-router`, on the other hand, doesn't create a `Vue` object.

```
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  history: true,
  linkActiveClass : 'active'
});

router.map({
  '/': {
    component: Home
  }
});

const App = Vue.extend(Index);
router.start(App, '#root');
```

So how do I declare my components?

Comment: Can you attach your `Home` component code?

Comment: Also have a look at https://vuejs.org/guide/application.html

Comment: you create a 'root' component that you use for router.start . the other components you will register with extend or vue.component (globally)

Answer (score 1):

This is my current setup in vue apps

```
var Vue = require('vue');
var VueRouter = require('vue-router');


// Use
Vue.use(require('vue-resource'));
Vue.use(VueRouter);


// Components
var site = Vue.component('site', require('./views/site/component.vue'));
var home = Vue.component('home', require('./views/home/component.vue'));
var search = Vue.component('search', require('./views/search/component.vue'));
var index = Vue.component('index', require('./views/index/component.vue'));

// Router
var router = new VueRouter({
    history: true
});
router.map({
    '/': {
        component: index
    },
    '/search': {
        component: search
    },
    '/profile': {
        component: home
    }
})


// Start App
router.start(site, 'body');
```

All 'major' components are declared globally with .component. Everything that I need at component level I declare with .extend. In vue-router, the 'site' component (in my case) acts as the $root.

Topmenu / sidebar are declared in the site component in the components section.
In the 'site' template i have only  and other shared components like topmenu / sidebar.

Answer (score 0):

you can try it instead,

```
import { alert } from 'vue-strap'
Vue.use(VueRouter);

const router = new VueRouter({
  history: true,
  linkActiveClass : 'active'
});

router.map({
  '/': {
    component: alert
  }
});

const App = Vue.extend(Index);
router.start(App, '#root');
```